# Events still fire--even after being "removed"

Tags: c#, events

I assign specific events to fields, depending on their use.

There are times, after updating database, when I want to repopulate field values.

I thought ahead to "remove" the events (-= eventhandler), for each field, prior to repopulating the data, however, when assigning the new values to the fields--the corresponding events still fire.  Why?

Is there something that should be "cleared out" to let the application know that the events have been "disabled?"

Comment: Generally what you propose should work.  Try to create a small, standalone repro.  If that doesn’t help you find the issue post the repro in the Andy of your question.

Comment: How is your code subscribing and un-subscribing to the event? Have you put a breakpoint on the lines of code that subscribe/un-subscribe from the event? I am guessing the event is getting re-subscribed to right after it has been un-subscribed. Watching the breakpoints would confirm this. Bottom line is that without some code to test, speculation and guesses are you will get. And, this will not be productive for YOU or anyone who tries to "guess" why the event is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any of the code, it's hard to know exactly what's going on. In general though, my guess is you're accidentally subscribed to the event multiple times so when you unsubscribe the handler still gets triggered.
If the event handler were previously firing multiple times would you be able to tell?
Also, quick correction on your terminology: the correct term for "removing" an event is "unsubscribing" from it. It's clearer when there are multiple things subscribed to one event.

Comment: MouseMove and MouseLeft--were causing my issues, as they subscribe/unsubscribe my fields, depending on what the user is doing at the time.  Ah-ha!